# How to apply Newton-Raphson method to Backward Euler method using built-in function numjac?

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, newtons-method

I am working on a program that solves the initial value problem for a system of differential equations via the theta method.

My code is as follows:

```
function [T,Y] = ivpSolver(f, S, y0, theta, h)
%INPUT
%f: a function-handle which describes the right-hand side f(t; u) of
%the differential equation
%S: a vector with requested points in time,
%u0: a column vector with initial conditions %u0
%theta: the parameter θ
%h: the step size h.
%OUTPUT
%T: a column vector of times T
%U: a matrix U with in every row the solution at the time corresponding to
%that row in T.

if length(S) == 2
    a = S(1);
    b = S(2);
end

T = zeros((b-a)/h,1);
Y = zeros((b-a)/h,1);
T(1) = t0;
Y(1) = y0;

tol = eps;
maxiter = 10;

for i = a:h:b
    T(i+1) = T(i) + h;

    %Calculation of new Y using Newton's method
    n_f = @(x) x - Y(i) - h*f(T(i+1),x);
    n_df = @(x)numjac(n_f, 0, Y(i) ,n_f(0, Y(i)), eps);
    ynew = newton(n_f,n_df,Y(i),tol,maxiter);

    Y(i+1) = Y(i) + h * ((1-theta)* f(T(i),Y(i))+ theta* f(T(i+1),ynew));
end

end
```

However, the part where I want to calculate the new value of y using Newton's Method, is not working properly. I think this is because the derivate, newton's method needs, is not inserted properly.

I want to use numjac to calculate this derivate. What do the inputs for numjac need to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/23776, `numjac` is exclusively intended to be used for ODE functions of the format `doty = f(t,y)`. And `n_df` should be the derivative of `n_f`, thus use the derivative of `f` in the iteration point `x`. Thus

```
n_f = @(x) x - Y(i) - h*f(T(i+1),x);
n_df = @(x) 1 - h*numjac(f, T(i+1), x ,f(T(i+1), x), eps);
```

---

There are other strange things in your code, if the above does not result in working code then:

- Check the logic of using `i in a:h:b` in conjunction with `T(i)` and `Y(i)`. The first follows an arithmetic sequence of real numbers while the second expects an integer.
- Deal with the fact that it often is not possible to go from `a` to exactly `b` in steps of length `h`. If `N = floor((b-a)/h)`, then one might need a last step of length `b-a-N*h`. Or redefine `h=(b-a)/N`.
- Your code at this time only works if `S` has exactly 2 elements and `y` is scalar.

Comment: Thanks for your tips, I will make changes in my code!